# How to use dynamic size in shared memory in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

For example I have below struct

```c
typedef struct myData{
  size_t fileSize;
  char* buffer; 
} myData;
```

buffer size is varied, can be decided  by user.  How to use this struct in shared memory between two process?

```c
// Reader 
sem_t lock
key_t key= ftok("/address", 1);
int shmID= shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666); //size can varied
myData* `buf = (myData*)shmat(shmID, 0, 0);

sem_init(&lock, 1, 0);
sem_wait(&lock)
//Process read
```

```c
//writer
sem_t lock
key_t key= ftok("/address", 1);
int shmID= shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666); //size can varied
myData* `buf = (myData*)shmat(shmID, 0, 0);

//write to buf
char str[10] = "Hello";
buf->fileSize = 100;
memcpy(buf->buffer, str, 0);
sem_post(&lock);
```

Comment: Why do you have a backtick before `buf`? Is that a copying error?

Comment: You generally can't put pointers into shared memory, because addresses don't match between processes.

Comment: I suggest you use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) instead.

Comment: You also never initialized `buf->buffer` before copying into it.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude . If use flexible array member, it will be allocated on heap. Heap cannot be used for shared memory between process. Could please raise a example?

Comment: @BecksWu "Allocate" the structure in the shared memory segment itself (just like you do now, but make sure the size of the segment is large enough to fit the strings you want to put into the structure).

Comment: The reader and writer cannot both use `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` on the same shared memory segment. At least one of them will fail. The first one to succeed will set the size.